# How can I use useEffect in React to run some code only when the component first mounts, and some other code whenever an event occurs (repeatedly)?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

If the title wasn't clear, I want to run some code when the component mounts, and some other code when a particular variable changes. I could add the variable in the [], but the problem is, I want some code to run only once, and not when the variable changes.

FYI: The variable is a window property

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the variable changes you want to run the effect once, is that once in the application life cycle or once in the component's life cycle? Components in the application can get mounted, unmounted and the mounted again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have two separate effects to handle each case.

**Case 1: when the component mounts**

```
useEffect(
  () => {
    // do something
  },
  [] // no dependency: run once
)
```

**Case 2: when the variable changes**

```
useEffect(
  () => {
    if (variable) {
      // do something
    }
  },
  [variable] // with dependency: run every time variable changes
)
```

Comment: @DarkProgrammer glad to be of help!